# Converting from Combobox double digit to int double digit

Tags: c#, int

```
Min = Convert.ToInt32(cbMin.SelectedItem);
```

Here's my issue, using that line to convert from the combobox to the integer variable. Right now, if i select "00" or "05" from my drop down the value only comes out as "0" or "5" It only seems to happen when a number STARTS with a "0"

Am i missing something?

PS: By the way, when I setup the combobox i just used the properties section on the side and filled out the collection. Just wanted to be sure that i threw that out there.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that you *don't* want `"05"` to be converted to `5`? If not, what *are* you expecting?

Comment: What the heck is a `int double` digit exactly?  Do you by chance mean a double which is a whole number?

Comment: Gabe yeah i don't want it to be converted over to "5" What i'm doing has to do with time, and I need that extra 0. 
GrantWinney Just for a time really. Converting from combobox to int then storing the value.
Ramhound I probably should have proof read this more. I mean't more like "int with that first digit" Was trying to make sure the name of the topic wasn't super long.

Comment: I would like to add to every answer: Just don't convert a numeric string to a number if you are not using it for make calculations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont convert value to integer if you want leading zero make use of string

```
i.ToString("00")
```

try this out soltuon will work for you

final code is

string s = (Convert.ToInt32(cbMin.SelectedItem)).ToString("00")

**EDIT**

if you alredy assinged valeu with 0 than you just need to write

```
string Min = cbMin.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Integers don't have leading zeros.  They are numeric data types. The leading zero is only possible in a string data type.

- int 0 is not the same as string "0"
- int 1 is not the same as string "1"

If you need to output the value with the leading 0, and never use it in mathematical claculations, you should keep it as a string. Don't convert it to an int in the first place.

If you need it as an integer to do calculations, then you need to convert it  to an int, but in places where you need the leading zero, format it.  Convert it back to a string and use data formatting to get the leading zero.

`"1".ToString("00")`  will result in "01".

`"15".ToString("00")` will result in "15".

For more information on formatting numeric data types, see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28VS.80%29.aspx) and the Custom Numeric Format Strings (as shown in my examples above) documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: i was not aware that leading zero's were only possible in string data type. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense make an integer `5` as `05` in *C#*. But if want a string has this format, you can do:

```
string Min = Convert.ToInt32(cbMin.SelectedItem).ToString("00");
```

Or

```
string Min = String.Format("{0:0#}", Convert.ToInt32(cbMin.SelectedItem));
```